# Find Index div and load attr. iframe url

Tags: jquery, iframe, indexing, attr

I have a menu list (ul/li) which I'm trying to match a certain set of div's. For example: if I would click in li number 3, the iframe nested in div 3 would have to 'show' and load a specific  url:

```
$('document').ready(function(){

$('ul li').one('click', function(event) {

    event.preventDefault();

    var index = $('ul li').index(this);


    $("#tab iframe").hide();
    $('#tab > div iframe:eq('+index+')').show();


    $('#tab > div iframe:eq('+index+')').attr("src", "http://mashable.com/");

    }); 

    });
```

So the problem is I want to load a specifi url for every other div iframe, as it is now there is no difference in url. Please look at the example: [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/47MZU/)

Comment: make an array for urls and get the url by index.

Comment: That crossed my mind, however I don't know how to do that..

Comment: ...Why not just set the urls in your html and keep the iframe hidden until you need it?

Comment: @nbrooks Because there are to many iframes. That would mean my page load would take a week or so

Comment: @youss Ok makes sense...it's still possible to store the the url as an attribute of the list-item, then create the iframe dynamically when the item is clicked. Doesn't get you much, but the logic is simpler than having a bunch of empty iframes and trying to figure out which corresponds to what link. Just an alternative idea anyway

Comment: @nbrooks I'm sure there are much more 'efficient' ways of doing this, but I'm a newbie so this basic stuff is what I understand (a bit) Thanks for the idea, maybe I will play with it in the future (for now Im on a deadline)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Youss, Use this

```
$('document').ready(function(){
   var URL = ["URL1", "URL2", "URL3"];
   $('ul li').one('click', function(event) {

   event.preventDefault();

   var index = $('ul li').index(this);


   $("#tab iframe").hide();
   $('#tab > div iframe:eq('+index+')').show();


   $('#tab > div iframe:eq('+index+')').attr("src", URL[index]);

  }); 

});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/47MZU/4/)**

Good Luck

Comment: @Youss, I made a syntax mistake in array declaration. I have updated my answer have a look.

Comment: Thank you for sticking around and solving my problem(:

Answer (score 1):

Here is some sample html code

```
    <ul>
        <li target="http://google.co.uk">li 1</li>
        <li target="http://webdesignseolondon.co.uk">li 2</li>
        <li target="http://marianzburlea.com">li 3</li>
    </ul>

    <div id="tab">
        <div><iframe  id="frame1" src="" scrolling="no" ></iframe></div>
        <div><iframe  id="frame2" src="" scrolling="no" ></iframe></div>
        <div><iframe  id="frame3" src="" scrolling="no" ></iframe></div>
    </div>
```

And here is your jQuery:

```
    (function(){

        $('ul li').one('click', function(e) {

            e.preventDefault();

            $("#tab iframe").hide();
            $('#frame'+$(this).index()).show();


            $('#frame'+$(this).index()).attr("src", $(this).attr('target'));

        });

    }) (jQuery);
```

Comment: Some links won't load because the pages loading will actually have some JavaScript code to prevent them from loading in iframes